# Setup a custom Docker registry on Ubuntu server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, registry, docker-registry

I am trying to setup a private docker registry on my Ubuntu server. This is my development server. I have been following below article:

URL: https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/

I understood all the things except one. I need to configure a registry hostname as well. Example: **somecompanyname.registry.local**. So that, I can push all my images like "somecompanyname.registry.local/imageone", "somecompanyname.registry.local/imagetwo", "somecompanyname.registry.local/imagethree".

Any idea?

**UPDATE:**

I am able to push using localhost.

[image]

I update the hostile as well. I would like to use custom hostname like somecompanyname.registry.local.

**UPDATE:**

I think that I almost done except one error. I setup TLS for the same but when I am trying to login OR use the registry, getting below error:

> Error: x509: certificate relies on legacy Common Name field, use SANs
> or temporarily enable Common Name matching with GODEBUG=x509ignoreCN=0

Comment: Add an entry in your `/etc/hosts` to resolve `127.0.0.1    somecompanyname.registry.local` or add a record in the nameserver your instance is configured with.

Comment: Thanks. Added an entry in the hostfile but did not work.

Comment: If your hosts file doesn't work then I'd suggest you start there e.g. https://serverfault.com/a/452269. If you can't e.g. ping your own localhost then not being able to resolve a host name to localhost sounds like the least of your problems, would be surprising though.